# Connfly 50-mil IDC mating part (types of socket/connector pairs)

Tags: connector, plug, socket, terminal

I am unable to find the right mating part (connector) for [this](https://www.tme.eu/en/details/ds1031-14-10s8b/pin-headers/connfly/) 50-mil contact pitch (supposedly) IDC socket. The groove in this particular socket has an offset, and I am unable to find any connector that fits this. The connfly website is rather unhelpful in this regard, as I am not even able to find this socket in their product list, let alone a mating part. It would be great if somebody could point me in the right direction, or has used similar sockets before.

Comment: Would this work? https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/te-connectivity-amp-connectors/5-111672-1/5-111672-1-ND/2261435

Comment: @12Lappie Close, but they are supposed to be regular connectors for hooking up boards together. It's rather weird that connfly themselves do not have a connector that mates to this, as far as I can find. It would be nice to have regular IDC connectors.

Comment: @12Lappie I checked. The groove seems to be flush to the edge on these TE connectivity connectors :( This is unlike the connfly sockets.

Comment: It seems like it's a board-to-board connector.

Comment: Why don't you email to sales@zhenqin.com.cn (from datasheet) and ask for mating counterparts? Tell them you would need 10,000 parts a week, they will respond...

Comment: Very interesting manufacturer. Thanks. It looks like the DS1031-14 is not current. This P/N points to a quite different connector. The identical part is now looks like DS1064-14, http://connfly.com/productshow.aspx?id=570 Maybe you can have a better luck finding the mate for this.

Comment: @AliChen I did notice that the product numbers changed. Very interesting indeed, they manufacture a 50 mil by 50 mil IDC connector but no socket, as far as I can see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes is better to do search by what you want. In your case: board-to-board connection and add filtering: 1.27mm pitch, 10-way.
Please check for AMPHENOL manuf. part no.: 87024-605LF
[RS-online](http://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/pcb-sockets/7142454/)
or
[DigiKey](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/amphenol-fci/87024-605LF/609-3157-ND/1525961)
also Samtec part no.:   ISDF-10-S-M or SFM-105-02-S-D-A-TR
[ISDF-10-S-M](http://www.newark.com/samtec/isdf-10-s-m/connector-housing-receptacle-10/dp/53R1235)
[SFM-105-02-S-D-A-TR](http://www.newark.com/samtec/sfm-105-02-s-d-a-tr/connector-receptacle-10-position/dp/97P5093)

Comment: Unfortunately, the issue was that I did not know this was a board to board connector. No website lists it under this category, and neither does connfly. The manufacturer has not only changed the product numbers on their website, they also do not have mating parts for a variety of components. For example, they manufacture a 50 mil IDC connector, but no accompanying socket.

I will have to simply use some (perhaps IDC style) header connectors for now. Nevertheless, this answer is correct and is the right mating part.

Comment: Great. I'm glad you found what you were looking for.

Comment: The key is in the key (pun intended). Look at the side-placed bump on Samtec parts, which is not there in the shroud shown in OP's picture. The Amphenol 87024 part also has only one edge-placed key, while the OP's shroud has two notches of different width on opposite ends of the shroud. So these are not the mating parts. Obviously you can shave some bumps to make them fit into the OP's shroud, but this is not a solution if quantities are involved.

Comment: Ali Chen: Are we talking about the same connector? I cannot see any different widths of notches, so CONNFLY DS1031-14-10S8B will easily fit to listed connectors, maybe except ISDF-10-S-M. After closer search, the datasheet on tme website does not even show the key and note below picture say 'The pictures of products are only demonstrative and may be different than the real look of products. It does not change their basic features.'  I did assume Shreyas Vinod has the connector somewhere in hand and he's looking for mating part for this particular connector.

Comment: @AliChen It only has one notch, on one side.

Comment: @smajli is correct, about the documentation too. The docs do not indicate the existence of this notch, which is why I missed it in the first place. I ended up manufacturing ~50ish boards with this footprint. Fortunately, they are only prototypes and it does not matter. Unfortunately, due to the high density of the board in question, I cannot just put on a different (proper) 50-mil IDC socket there and expect it to fit. It was rather silly of me to not check this. I've decided to temporarily whack on some 50-mil SMT headers as a replacement.